# Enabling markdown highlighting in Vim

Tags: vim, markdown

I'm using Vim in a terminal on my MacBook Air with OS X Lion, and I can't seem to find a good plugin for Markdown syntax highlighting.

So far I've tried the [plasticboy](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/) plugin and [Tim Pope's plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown). The plasticboy plugin worked OK but was causing white space at the end of lines to be highlighted, and I haven't figured out how to turn that off. (It's really annoying, because every time I hit `space` when I'm writing it highlights the character.)

Tim's plugin didn't seem to do very much in the way of highlighting, other than maybe headers that use `###`. Code blocks and bullets are ignored. I might be missing something there. I do use the `.md` extension on my Markdown files, so it should be picking up the filetype.

I've also seen a reference to Vim 7.3 having Markdown support built in, but without one of those two plugins I don't get any highlighting at all.

Do either of these require specific color schemes to work?

Comment: `*.md` is not the right extension for markdown. That one is for modula files. Tpope plugin works fine (all this plugins works fine) You should use the `*.markdown` extension

Comment: @lucapette the ftdetect for Tim Pope's plugin **does** also include `*.md`, along with: `*.markdown,*.mdown,*.mkd,*.mkdn`. The plasticboy plugin auto-detects only `*.mkd,*.markdown,*.mdwn`

Comment: From the plasticboy plugin source, it looks like it actually does detect `.md` as well. I'm locked into this extension for now because I'm using [Scriptogr.am](http://scriptogr.am) for my blog, and that's the only extension they recognize right now.

Comment: Just found this and it's pretty rockin for github flavored markdown: https://github.com/jtratner/vim-flavored-markdown

Comment: For issues with [plasticboy/vim-markdown](https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown), please open issues on the projects so that devs can solve it. I find that highlighing trailing whitespaces is a good behavior as double spaces generate `<br>` tags, so writers should be made aware of that.

Comment: @pb2q not anymore: https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftdetect/mkd.vim

Comment: scroll down to the second answer if you just want to see how to switch on the default highlighting

Comment: @lucapette some of the biggest users of markdown are gitlab and github and they are using .md for their markdown files.

Comment: Note that some default does not handle math formulas like `$...$`. Refer to [Vim syntax and Latex math inside markdown - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865744/vim-syntax-and-latex-math-inside-markdown) for more details.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should work to disable the end-of-line space highlighting when using the plasticboy mkd plugin:

```
:syn clear mkdLineBreak
```

You could `autocmd` that for the necessary file extensions so that you needn't do it every time you load a markdown file.

**Note** that this specific highlight exists because Markdown treats lines ending with 2 or more space characters specially by inserting a `<br>`, so it is useful.

The plasticboy plugin uses `TODO` highlighting for this rule, which **is** a bit too much as it's designed to, by default, be really garish - yellow background - so that it stands out. You can make this less visually striking by changing that `highlight` rule. One quick way to do this would be something like:

```
:hi link mkdLineBreak Underlined
```

Now those end-of-line spaces will show up as underlined. Try linking to other `highlight` groups for something that may appeal to you more. Instead of using `link` you can get even more specific about those end-of-line spaces: for instance you could specify that they show up as just slightly lighter/darker than the normal background, using your own `highlight` command, specifying custom *ctermfg*, *ctermbg*, *guifg*, *guibg* settings.

As above, you could `autocmd` this to apply your specific settings.

For more information about link `highlight` groups, type: `:help group-name` and you'll see a list of groups that can be linked that themselves should helpfully be displayed using their current `highlight` rules. Also: `:help highlight`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Didn't realize that two spaces had significance in Markdown. I think I'll leave it enabled unless it keeps bugging me. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah that's why the highlight doesn't kick in until 2 spaces have been entered.

Comment: @josh-earl see my edits for more alternatives when using the plasticboy plugin

Answer (score 321):

About the native syntax highlight for markdown I think it only works for files with the extension `.markdown` by default.
I was having problems with markdown syntax highlight for my `.md` files.
I tried:

```
:set syntax=markdown
```

And it worked.
So i included the following line in my `.vimrc`:

```
au BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown
```

Now my vim have syntax highlight for my `.md` files.

BufFilePre is [needed for :sav](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084243/588759)

Comment: For anyone else reading this: yes it works and is a much simpler solution to the problem than installing a plugin. Fast way to do this from command line: echo "au BufRead,BufNewFile *.md set filetype=markdown" >> .vimrc

Comment: It seems to me that this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: IS there a bug files for vim to change this behaviour?

Comment: @SamStoelinga It's not a bug, `.md` is also used by Modula. Detecting which one to use would require some advanced heuristics.

Comment: As of Vim 7.4.480, `*.md` files are recognized as Markdown by default.

Comment: @fwalch: Using Vim 7.4 as well, and the syntax highlight was not correct on `.md` files until I entered `:set syntax=markdown`.

Comment: @sheac: Do you have a version >= 7.4.480? If you have a look at https://code.google.com/p/vim/source/detail?r=31f7581068a9c3119e3bd2cd74160eb8282c3c6e, `runtime/filetype.vim` is updated to set `*.md` files to markdown. The next tagged version is 7.4.480.

Comment: @fwalch, hmm... probably not. `:version` only gives me "7.4", but it was released in 2013, while the source you link to is from 2014.

Comment: Correct, but incomplete. For this to equally work with the `Save As… :sav` command, one needs to extend the autocommand to `BufFilePre`:
`autocmd BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown`

Comment: Thank goodness!  I'm operating inside a vagrant box, and needing to set up a vim plugin each time I `vagrant up` would be a real pain...this is MUCH simpler.  Should be the accepted solution.

Comment: @putzkipa YTMND!

Comment: `:set syntax=markdown` worked nicely for me but the `autocmd...` didn't work with `README` without the `.md` tail. but the workaround changing its name to `readme.md` worked perfectly but quite inconvenient. have anyone had a real solution for this?

Answer (score 25):

## Native syntax highlighting

Native syntax highlighting for Markdown only works by default for the `.markdown` file extension.

The following line in `.vimrc` yields the best results for both `vim` and `gvim`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown.pandoc
```

Explanation:

### 1. Specify your Markdown flavour!

If you work with mainly one flavour of Markdown (e.g. [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html)), be sure to mention this as well! Doing so, allows for mixing and matching of both Markdown- and Pandoc-specific Vim plug-ins. For example: I have found the [vim-pandoc-syntax](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax) plug-in particularly suitable for my highlighting needs. Nevertheless, I use the more general [vim-markdown-folding](https://github.com/nelstrom/vim-markdown-folding) for Markdown folding.

By the way, only one flavour is allowed, separated by a dot, e.g.: `filetype=markdown.pandoc`

### 2. `gvim` requires `BufFilePre`

`gvim` requires an additional [`BufFilePre`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufFilePre) in the autocommand line for Markdown file type recognition with the `Save As… :sav` command.

Answer (score 16):

In [Tim's plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown) the **.md** extension works only for **README.md**  because **filetype.vim** specifies so.

```
" Markdown
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.markdown,*.mdown,*.mkd,*.mkdn,README.md  setf markdown
```

Comment: False; you must be thinking of the default Vim install, which behaves in this manner. Tim's plugin overrides it for all .md files. See https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/blob/master/ftdetect/markdown.vim

Answer (score 7):

If you don't like putting all of your configuration in `~/.vimrc`, you can create `~/.vim/ftdetect/markdown.md` (or its equivalent on Windows) with the following contents.

`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.md setf markdown`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how recent this is, but in my `.vimrc` this works natively, per  [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/fk48jw/markdown_code_syntax_highlighting/) and https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown ,

```
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
let g:markdown_fenced_languages = ['html', 'python', 'bash=sh']
```

Using vim installed with `brew install macvim` on macOS Monterey

```
vim --version|head -5
VIM - Vi IMproved 9.0 (2022 Jun 28, compiled Feb 07 2023 11:35:56)
macOS version - x86_64
Included patches: 1-1276
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```