# Markdown syntax coloring for less (pager)

Tags: markdown, pager

When I use vim to edit a markdown file I have nice syntax coloring (via vim-markdown and vim-markdown-preview plug-ins).

I would like to have this same syntax coloring when I am using less (pager) to view a file.  Is there a way to get less to do this syntax coloring? or is there another pager that has this functionality?

Comment: I also looked at [highlight](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/highlight/en/highlight.php) which works similarly and has nicer (imho) output colors. `LESSOPEN="| /usr/local/bin/highlight --out-format=xterm256 %s"`

Comment: Also, found [vimpager](https://github.com/rkitover/vimpager) which gives me the same syntax coloring as vim :))  It works well if you use a stripped down version of your .vimrc as .vimpagerrc See [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_syntax-highlighting_pager) for some suggestions.

Comment: I wound up setting up my bash config so my PAGER so that it would  prefer vimpager or less using highlight, then src-hilite-lesspipe.sh.

Comment: You should put your first comment into an answer - does a better job (actually answers the question) than the accepted answer

Comment: Suggestion: Use more comments in your code.
Because: If another user has Deuteranopia, colours may seem similar and/or may not have enough contrast with the background colour.
[WCAG: Accessible colour and contrast ratios](https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/wcag-accessible-colour-and-contrast-ratios-5e94ea3f81f4 "WCAG: Accessible colour and contrast ratios").
[Designing the Terminal for color accessibility](https://www.bloomberg.com/ux/2021/10/14/designing-the-terminal-for-color-accessibility/ "Designing the Terminal for color accessibility").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now use, from best to worse, `vimpager`, `pigmentize`, `highlight`, `src-hilite-lesspipe.sh`, `less`, and then `more`; using bash to determine what is available on whichever system I am on.
Here is what I finally arrived at:

`.bash_profile`:

```
#############################################
#   Pager                                   #
#############################################
PAGER='more'
export PAGER

if type less &> /dev/null; then
  LESS='-i -R -e -X -z-2 -M -P%t?f%f :stdin .?pb%pb\%:?lbLine %lb:?bbByte %bb:-...'
  LESSCHARSET='utf-8'
  LESSHISTFILE=-
  PAGER='less'
  MANPAGER='less'

  export LESS LESSCHARSET LESSHISTFILE PAGER MANPAGER

  export LESS_TERMCAP_so="$(tput bold; tput setaf 0; tput setab 4)"    # begin standout
  export LESS_TERMCAP_se="$(tput sgr0)"                                # end   standout
  export LESS_TERMCAP_us="$(tput smul; tput setaf 3)"                  # begin underscore
  export LESS_TERMCAP_ue="$(tput rmul; tput sgr0)"                     # end   underscore
  export LESS_TERMCAP_mr="$(tput rev)"                                 # begin reverse
  export LESS_TERMCAP_mb="$(tput blink)"                               # begin blink
  export LESS_TERMCAP_mh="$(tput dim)"                                 # begin dim
  export LESS_TERMCAP_md="$(tput bold; tput setaf 6)"                  # begin bold
  export LESS_TERMCAP_ZH="$(tput sitm)"                                # begin italics
  export LESS_TERMCAP_ZR="$(tput ritm)"                                # end   italics
  export LESS_TERMCAP_me="$(tput sgr0)"                                # end all modes

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
  [ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(lesspipe)"

  if type src-hilite-lesspipe.sh &> /dev/null; then
    export LESSOPEN="| src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
  fi

  if type highlight &> /dev/null; then
    export LESSOPEN="| highlight --out-format=xterm256 --style=solarized-dark %s"
  fi

  if type pygmentize &> /dev/null; then
    export LESSOPEN="| pygmentize -O style=solarized-dark -f terminal256 %s"
  fi

fi

if type vimpager &> /dev/null; then
  export PAGER='vimpager'
fi

if type vimcat &> /dev/null; then
  alias v='vimcat'
fi
```

Comment: Note: `have` is a bash function that checks if a command is available.

Comment: This answer would be improved if you either included your `have` function, or (better) substituted something universally available which doesn't use a subshell.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/how-can-i-check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212

Comment: @mc0e updated to not need a subshell.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to view GitHub markdown files in a console using `less`.

1. Install `pandoc` and `lynx`.

   a. For Ubuntu (and WSL): `sudo apt install pandoc lynx`

   b. For MacOS: `brew install pandoc lynx`
2. Name the following script file as `less` and save it somewhere on the `PATH`, for example `/usr/local/bin`
3. Make the script executable, for example `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/less`
4. Type `hash -r` or `/usr/bin/less` will run instead of this script

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "${1##*.}" == md ]; then
  pandoc "$1" | lynx -stdin
else
  /usr/bin/less "$1"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [e2ansi](https://github.com/Lindydancer/e2ansi), a package that use Emacs in batch mode to perform syntax highlighting. You can configure `less` to use it by defining the LESSOPEN environment variable.

To get Emacs to syntax highlight MarkDown, you will also need to install [markdown-mode](http://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/).

(Finally, to get the same syntax highlighting in `less` as you have in your editor, I guess you would have to switch to Emacs ;) Of course, given that Emacs comes with a Vim compatibility package called Evil Mode, it might not be as bad as it seems.)

Answer (score 0):

With [Vim Markdown highlighting (and folding)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30113820/2192488) up and running, the most straightforward solution is to evoke `vim` in the read only mode with either `vim -R`, or (at least on Ubuntu) more elegantly:

```
$ view filename.md
```

Add the following at the very bottom of your `.vimrc` file, and `view` will behave just like `less` with the added benefit of your favourite syntax highlighting (not only for markdown!) and folding:

```
" less behaviour for view
" https://stackoverflow.com/a/39836959/2192488

" http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_a_syntax-highlighting_pager
function! LessBehaviour()
    if (!&modifiable || &ro)
        set nonumber
        set nospell
        set laststatus=0    " Status line
        set cmdheight=1
        set guioptions=aiMr    " No menu bar, nor tool bar
        noremap u <C-u>
        noremap d <C-d>
        noremap q :q<CR>
    endif
endfunction

" https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9101/3168
augroup ReadOnly
    au!
    au VimEnter * :call LessBehaviour() 
augroup END
```

There exists also a more rigorous `less.sh` script. On my system, it comes packaged with `vim`. To find it, use:

```
$ find /usr/share/vim -name less.sh
```

However, contrary to the script listed above, folding will not work with this `less.sh`.

Answer (score -3):

`less` itself doesn't support syntax highlighting, but you could use [`GNU-source-highlight`](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/) which does.

First, you'd need to install it. E.g., on RHEL/Centos/Fedora (as root):

```sh
$ yum install source-highlight
```

On Debian/Ubuntu

```sh
$ apt-get install source-highlight
```

Then configure your pager to use it:

```sh
$ export LESSOPEN="| /usr/bin/src-hilite-lesspipe.sh %s"
$ export LESS=" -R"
```

Now, it should just replace `less`:

```sh
$ less README.md # pager with syntax highlighting
```

Comment: As anyone actually had results with this method? On ubuntu 14.04 this does add syntax highlighting for less, but it does not support Markdown ; it makes sense since Markdown is not listed on https://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/

Comment: There is an open bug for Markdown support here: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?46542

Comment: It should be : apt-get install source-highlight

Comment: @muenalan indeed, not sure how I missed that. Edited and fixed. Thanks for noticing!

Comment: As of today, source-highlight still does not support markdown (which actually makes this answer *not* answer the original question).