# Vim syntax and Latex math inside markdown

Tags: vim, latex, markdown, pandoc, vim-syntax-highlighting

I write documentation in markdown using ViM and I also put math using the latex `$$` symbol (I compile using pandoc). The thing is that ViM syntax wouldn't ignore the underscores `_` inside the dollar symbols and it is pretty annoying. For instance if I write this:

`$$ a_1 = 0 $$`

Then Vim will highlight all the following text as italics due to to the underscore used.

How can I change that?

Also it would be nice if I could highlight what's inside `$` with a different format.

Comment: Is it happening even if you use [vim-pandoc-syntax](https://github.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax/)?

Comment: Related: [Syntax highlight Markdown formulas using LaTeX highlighting](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16376/5324)

Answer (score 18):

I have put these lines in my .vimrc. It works for inline math on the same line and block-mode math.

```
" This gets rid of the nasty _ italic bug in tpope's vim-markdown
" block $$...$$
syn region math start=/\$\$/ end=/\$\$/
" inline math
syn match math '\$[^$].\{-}\$'

" actually highlight the region we defined as "math"
hi link math Statement
```

*Edit: I've since written a blog post called [Vim syntax highlighting for Markdown, Liquid and MathJax](https://stsievert.com/blog/2016/01/06/vim-jekyll-mathjax/).*

Comment: Thanks, works great! I've put the code in ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim to keep .vimrc clean.

Comment: I have to put it in `~/.vim/after/syntax/markdown.vim` instead (however, errors are impossible to debug if you don't understand vim syntax commands well. [The question on Vi.SE](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/16376) has a link to a plugin that can be used)

Comment: Alternatively `vim-pandoc-syntax` and some other plugins also have support for Markdown syntax

Comment: The blog post entry is worth a look.  It is a more complete solution.