# How to make Vim highlight Latex environments in Markdown

Tags: vim, markdown, pandoc

I use pandoc a lot which means that I write with a mix of markdown and latex a lot. The problem is that I can't make Vim highlight Latex as it should, even though pandoc understands it.

For example, the following snipet

```
# Header 1

Variable $x_0$ is defined as
\begin{align}
x_0=y_0^2
\end{align}
```

If I name it `test.md` Vim only sees markdown and fails to highlight `$x_0$` and the `align` environment. I can make the situation a little bit better if I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865744/vim-syntax-and-latex-math-inside-markdown) then I can at least make the `$ $` highlighted.

As a quick workaround I found that by naming the file with a `.Rmd` extension I get the `$ $` to work, although that isn't strictly correct I guess.

But so far I have not been able to get both Markdown Syntax and Latex syntax simultaneously. Is there a way that can be done?

PS: I'm really trying to avoid installing obscure Vim plugins that need Vundle etc in the name of portability!

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to get something that complex without a plugin, and Vim does not include a LaTeX plugin (nor does its Markdown plugin seem to understand LaTeX math). I would suggest you look at https://github.com/plasticboy/vim-markdown for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The work around I found (almost by accident) was to copy [this file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim-pandoc/vim-pandoc-syntax/master/syntax/pandoc.vim), which is a syntax file for Pandoc, into `ftplugin` and add these lines to `vimrc`

```
augroup pandoc_syntax
    au! BufNewFile,BufFilePre,BufRead *.md set filetype=markdown.pandoc
augroup END
```

This is actually part of a plugin. But I found that this way is much simpler than having the whole plugin installed and much more portable.

Comment: Why not directly install this plugin? Manually copying files is cumbersome.