# How to disable vim markdown syntax highlight

Tags: vim, markdown, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am using a setup where I keep a journal in markdown and have latex code. The trouble is that inside the latex code there are signs that are read as markdown operations and this causes vim to draw some syntax over the second "<".

Is there a way to prevent all syntax highlighting within two pairs of $?

```
# TEST
* $a < b < c $
```

Comment: Does it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32865744/vim-syntax-and-latex-math-inside-markdown ?

Comment: Thanks! After some more digging around, it seems like it depends on which vim markdown plugin one is using. I use vim-markdown and the option for me was  let g:vim_markdown_math = 1