# Looking for plugin/way how to highlight syntax in `.md` files in Vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way/plugin to enable syntax highlighting in `.md` files in Vim?

````
```js  //will highlight javascript

```py  //will do python etc
````

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779012/7976758

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

1. ':syntax on' then ':set syntax=markdown'
2. you can try installing a plugin such as plastic boy. If you go ahead with this solution and it caused white space at the end of lines to be highlighted. Check out this fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10964847/14944117