# How do I get vim to stop treating the apostrophe (ASCII 0x27) as the begining or end for highlighting a string literal in markdown?

Tags: vim, markdown

Given this example markdown text, the single apostrophes (ASCII 0x27) used for possessives and contractions keep getting highlighted as the begining or end of string literals, e.g. the substring `'s or user'` is highlighted in the color I've seet for string literals in my color scheme.

```
# Heading 1

If use use an apostrophe for an English posessive or contraction, such as it's
or users's, it treats it as the begining or end of a string literal in a
markdown file.
```

I've tried installing and configuring a few Markdown plugins based on [Enabling markdown highlighting in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964681/enabling-markdown-highlighting-in-vim).  None of the answers or comments helped me figure it out.

I am expecting that, out of the box once the right plugins are installed and my .vimrc is configured properly, when I open a markdown file, apostrophes (ASCII 0x27) will not be treated as the begining or end of string literal highlighting, and instead as just a character used in standard English grammar for posessives and contractions.

Comment: Try https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown

Comment: The built-in syntax highlighting doesn't do what you describe. Figure out which of your plugins is responsible for that and use their issue tracker.

Comment: You realize the question you refer to is 12 years old? You need not install any plugin to get markdown support with a recent version of Vim.